# Perl: using stat()

Tags: perl, filehandle

I am trying to use stat() in a perl script.
I have read the documentation on perldocs that says to use it like this:

```
$mode = (stat($filename))[2];
```

But this does not work:

```
$mode = (stat($filename))[2];
print $mode;

Use of uninitialized value $mode in print at ...
```

I think another syntax is needed to access the values returned by stat. Data::dumper returns this structure:

```
   @stat = stat($filename);
   print Dumper(@stat);

  $VAR1 = bless( [
   48,
   305368,
   33188,
   1,
   0,
   0,
   0,
   '2011',
   1397569653,
   1397569653,
   1397569653,
   4096,
   8
  ], 'File::stat' );
```

Comment: You're reading the wrong documentation. Look at the docs for [File::stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/stat.html), which is what you're using in that example.

Comment: After your edit, what is the problem?The stat function returns an array giving the status info for the given file.

Comment: @PseftiS, no, it returns a blessed arrayref.  But that syntax is expecting `stat` to return a list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently, you also have the line

```
use File::stat;
```

in your program, and forgot to mention it.  [File::stat](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::stat) overrides the built-in `stat` function with a version that returns objects.  You should read [its documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::stat) instead.

In your case, you'd want:

```
use File::stat;

my $mode = stat($filename)->mode;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with an array slice (stat $filename)[2]